# Firefox incorrectly applies vertical margin to inline elements

Tags: css, firefox

I believe that in theory vertical margins should not be applied to inline elements.  However, in the following example, Firefox applies the `margin-top` to the `<b>` element (and the `<a>` element also has some vertical top spacing, though I'm not sure where that comes from).  Every other browser I have tried does not do this, i.e. the `<b>` element follows the `<a>` element one line below, with no extra margin between them.  I'm using Firefox 39.0.

Is this a bug in Firefox, or does Firefox get it right?  Anyone know an easy workaround?

```css
* + * {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="#" class="internal-link">The Link</a>
    <br>
    <b>September 23, 6:30-8:30 pm</b>
    <br>
    Eros odio legentis gothica videntur liber. Euismod lectores imperdiet augue putamus insitam. Typi vulputate parum praesent mirum hendrerit. 
</p>
<p>
    <a href="#" class="internal-link">The Link</a>
    <br>
    <b>September 23, 6:30-8:30 pm</b>
    <br>
    Eros odio legentis gothica videntur liber. Euismod lectores imperdiet augue putamus insitam. Typi vulputate parum praesent mirum hendrerit. 
</p>
```

Comment: `*+*` is a flaky way to select ... it essentially means: _anyTag_ preceded by _anyTag_ ... in other words: _Anything after anything_.

Comment: Ole Sauffaus, exactly...  it's the "axiomatic lobotomized owl selector":  http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls

Comment: You have come across a content layout situation that is not well specified in the CSS specification, which is a bit of a curiosity. Well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, the `br` element can take on a top/bottom margin value.

If you zero it out, you get the expected behavior.

**Note:** There seems to be some ambiguity in the CSS specification about how to deal with empty line boxes (a line with no content).  For example, if you read:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height

"Empty inline elements generate empty inline boxes, but these boxes still have margins, padding, borders and a line height..." and this could be interpreted as meaning that `<br>` elements can be assigned a top/bottom margin.  This seems to be how Firefox interpreted the specification, but Chrome took another approach.

See also the following archived discussions:

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Jun/0232.html

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/br-spacing-line-height/4854

I like the view that `br` elements were not meant to be styled, so some browsers ignored any specified line height or margin values.  You just happened to pick a selector that applies to the `br` element.

```css
* + * {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
br {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="#" class="internal-link">The Link</a>
    <br>
    <b>September 23, 6:30-8:30 pm</b>
    <br>
    Eros odio legentis gothica videntur liber. Euismod lectores imperdiet augue putamus insitam. Typi vulputate parum praesent mirum hendrerit. 
</p>
<p>
    <a href="#" class="internal-link">The Link</a>
    <br>
    <b>September 23, 6:30-8:30 pm</b>
    <br>
    Eros odio legentis gothica videntur liber. Euismod lectores imperdiet augue putamus insitam. Typi vulputate parum praesent mirum hendrerit. 
</p>
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that Firebug or the other developer tools show the `margin-top` on the wrong elements, then.  When I hover on top of the `<b>`, for example, I see the yellow `margin-top`, but not when on the `<br>`.